# Calling function with optional arguments with PyObject_CallMethod

Tags: python, c++, c, python-2.7, python-3.x

Using Python C API, how can I call a function with optional arguments?

For example, assuming there is a Python module `add_module.py` with a function `add` that goes like:

```
def add(a=0, b=0):
  return a + b
```

`add(1, 2)` would correspond to

```
PyObject *add_module = PyImport_ImportModule("add_module");
PyObject *result = PyObject_CallMethod(add_module, "add", "ii", 1, 2);
```

How would I call something like `add(b=5)` using the Python API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling with keyword arguments is not that straightforward from C, and you need to do `PyObject_Call`, which requires 3 arguments:

1. The first argument of `PyObject_Call` is the method object
2. The second argument of `PyObject_Call` is the empty tuple for *args
3. The third argument is the keyword dictionary

Thus we get

```
PyObject *function = PyObject_GetAttrString(add_module, "add");
PyObject *args = PyTuple_New(0);
PyObject *kwargs = Py_BuildValue("{s:i}", "b", 5)
result = PyObject_Call(function, args, kwargs);

Py_DECREF(kwargs);
Py_DECREF(args);
Py_DECREF(function);
```

**except** you **must** NULL-check the return values from the 4 first functions (omitted for brevity).